# android studio duplicate resources

Tags: android, xml

I'm getting these duplicate resources errors.

```
[color/colorAccent] C:\Users\haide\Documents\androidProjects\SkyrimGenerator\SkyrimScenarioCharacterGenerator\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml   [color/colorAccent] C:\Users\haide\Documents\androidProjects\SkyrimGenerator\SkyrimScenarioCharacterGenerator\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[color/colorPrimary] C:\Users\haide\Documents\androidProjects\SkyrimGenerator\SkyrimScenarioCharacterGenerator\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml  [color/colorPrimary] C:\Users\haide\Documents\androidProjects\SkyrimGenerator\SkyrimScenarioCharacterGenerator\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[color/colorPrimaryDark] C:\Users\haide\Documents\androidProjects\SkyrimGenerator\SkyrimScenarioCharacterGenerator\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml  [color/colorPrimaryDark] C:\Users\haide\Documents\androidProjects\SkyrimGenerator\SkyrimScenarioCharacterGenerator\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[style/AppTheme] C:\Users\haide\Documents\androidProjects\SkyrimGenerator\SkyrimScenarioCharacterGenerator\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml  [style/AppTheme] C:\Users\haide\Documents\androidProjects\SkyrimGenerator\SkyrimScenarioCharacterGenerator\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

Here is my colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Here is my styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and strings.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

This happened after I changed my strings.xml invalidated cache and restarted because it wouldn't update.

I tried multiple permutations of having just one apptheme and one color in a single file, but I get compilation errors. Say I delete apptheme from strings.xml and colors from color.xml, I'll get compilation error. If I have any two duplicates it'll give me duplicate error...

Does anyone know how to fix the error?

Comment: you should not put the style inside `string.xml`, put it in `styles.xml`

Comment: I didn't put styles inside string.xml, I think it got placed in there after I invalidated cache and restarted because it wan't in there before, same with colors attributes and dimesions, all got placed in strings.xml, when they weren't there before

Comment: I see in your question, style is in `string.xml`. Please check your question again

Comment: Yes, don't know how it got there, When I was editing the strings.xml it wasn't there, but after I invalidated cache and restarted, it may have caused all the styles to go into strings.xml? I don't know why. But that code is what I have, the styles went into strings.xml. I tried removing it but am getting compilation errors. I might just replace this with my older version on the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue once... I noticed that i had declared the variable colorPrimary in the app level build.gradle file and also in colors.xml. I fixed the error by removing the resource value in the build.gradle file

I had this in my app level build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
   ...

    resValue 'color', "colorPrimary", "#2196F3"

}
```

And this in my colors.xml

```
    <color name="colorPrimary">#C41426</color>
```

I removed one of them problem solved